# Looking for a Menu System like Bonobos.com

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to find a menu system that I can build a website navigation similar to http://www.bonobos.com/.  I need it to have drop downs with a static image within each drop down.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far? What have you tried? What mark-up are you working with?

Comment: Can't you just modify their code to fit your needs? :)

Comment: I'd start by making a regular dropdown (maybe building off one of the many opensource starting points available for this e.g. http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-drop-down-menus/ ) and then just adjusting the CSS such that there was extra space to the right of the dropdown content, and set that space to have the appropriate background image depending on which dropdown option was set.

Comment: I'm building one, trying at least, only with CSS. Incredibly is working in Safari, Opera, Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working wonders but works without java script (opera,safari,firefox,chrome).
The jQuery code is not needed, is just to add (try to) some effect, but is not working well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Horizontal Dropdown CSS Menu</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                text-decoration:none;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:none;
                list-style:none
            }
            html{background-color:#999}
            body{
                font: 12px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
                color:#000;
                text-align:center
            }
            #wrapper {
                display:block;
                margin:auto;
                width:1024px;
                height:100%;
                background-color:#aaa;
                border:#ccc groove 2px
            }
            #content {
                width:auto;
                height:auto;
                background-color:#fff
            }
            #nav {
                position:relative;
                display:table;
                text-align:left;
                width:100%;
                height:30px;
                margin:auto;
                background-color:#eee;
                border-bottom:#eee groove 2px
            }
            #horizon-menu {
                float:left;
                clear:both;
                width:800px;
                height:30px;
                font-weight:700;
                background-color:#eee
            }
            #horizon-menu li {display:inline-block;height:30px}
            #horizon-menu li a {display:block;padding:6px;text-decoration:none;color:#555}
            #horizon-menu li ul li {display:none}
            #horizon-menu li a:hover {padding:6px;background-color:#fff}
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul {
                display:inline-block;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:1000;
                float:left;
                clear:none;
                min-width:200px;
                width:auto;
                min-height:160px;
                height:auto;
                margin:3px 0 0 -2px;
                /*padding:2px;*/
                border:#eee groove 2px;
                background-color:#eee
            }
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul img {display:inline;float:left;clear:none}
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul a img {background-color:transparent}
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul li {
                display:inline-block;
                width:auto;
                height:auto;
                float:left;
                clear:both;
                /*padding:2px*/
            }
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul li a {display:block;color:#555;text-decoration:none}
            #horizon-menu li:hover ul div a {display:block}
            #horizon-menu li:hover div {
                float:left;
                clear:none;
                margin-right:2px;
                min-width:160px;
                width:auto;
                min-height:150px;
                height:auto;
                background-color:#ddd
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a').bind('click', function(){
                    alert('f!');
                })
                $('#nav, #horizon-menu li ul div').css('display','none');
                $('#nav').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
                $('#horizon-menu li a').bind({
                    mouseenter: function(){
                        $('#horizon-menu li ul div').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
                    },
                    mouseover: function(){
                        $('#horizon-menu li ul div').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
                    }
                });
                $('#horizon-menu li ul').bind({
                    mouseleave: function(){
                        $('#horizon-menu li ul div').fadeTo("slow", 0);
                    },
                    mouseout: function(){
                        $('#horizon-menu li ul div').fadeTo("slow", 0);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul id="horizon-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">MacBook Pro</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" title="">Link 1</a>
                                    <a href="#" title="">Link 2</a>
                                    <a href="#" title="">Link 3</a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://images.apple.com/home/images/promo_macbookpro_20110302.png" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">MacBook Air</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MacBook</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" title="">MacBook</a>
                                    <a href="#" title="">Wow!</a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="http://images.apple.com/home/images/promo_macbookpro_20110302.png" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h1><img src="http://images.apple.com/macbookair/images/performance_title20101020.png" alt="Might made light." height="46" width="333"></h1>
                <p class="intro">Don’t be fooled by the sliver-thin profile of <a class="ml-smartlink" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook">MacBook</a> Air. This small wonder features powerful NVIDIA graphics, an Intel Core 2 Duo processor, lightning-fast flash storage, and long battery life. So while looks may be deceiving, performance doesn’t lie.</p>
                <img src="http://images.apple.com/macbookair/images/bg_hardware_20101020.png" alt="" height="441" width="705" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```